# "entered too many arguments for this function" 4 arguments, nested if

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have been trying to figure this out for a good while, but just cant get it. I have no idea what I've done wrong in this formula.

I think that it is a nested `IF` formula but it still says `entered too many arguments for this function`.

```
=IF(C12={0,1,2,3,4,5},"0","", IF(C12={6,7,8},"25","", IF(C12={9,10},"30","", IF(C12>10,"35",""))))
```

Can someone please tell me what i'm doing wrong here?

Edit: Thanks to @timotree my original problem is solved. But now a new one has arose, now that the cells are correctly showing what i want them to automatically it seems i cannot sum them together. For example this formula is used in cells E12-E21, i want to total these cells in E22. But as it is now i am only getting 0 even if cells E12-E21 are populated with values from 25-35.

Edit 2: 2nd problem solved again by @timotree, thanks to everyone else for helping as well.

Comment: For the future, this probably should've gone on [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com).

Comment: @timotree No, it shouldn't. Formula questions are a perfect fit for SuperUser, too.

Comment: @timotree Also, at-mentioning only works if you spell the name correctly..... there is a pop up that helps you do that.

Comment: @teylyn I know how to use the site. I appreciate your advice but you could be a little less condescending about my typo. :-P

Comment: The problem is that you are putting the numbers in quotes (`""`) try putting them without quotes. (Specifically change `"0"` -> `0`, `"25"` -> `25`, `"30"` -> `30`, and `"35"` -> `35`.

Comment: Wow, it was that simple, i was amusing the quotes were required because of every tutorial/guide I've seen on these types of formulas. Thank you very much for the help, i will not forget it.

Comment: @tonygouveia My pleasure!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Examples

Actual IF syntax

```
=IF(logical_expression, value_if_true, value_if_false)
```

[*source*](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093364?hl=en)

The way you used it was

```
=IF(C12={0,1,2,3,4,5},"0","", IF(C12={6,7,8},"25","", IF(C12={9,10},"30","", IF(C12>10,"35",""))))
              PROBLEM IS HERE ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

This translates to

```
=IF(logical_expression, value_if_true, value_if_false, another_if_statement)
                                     PROBLEM IS HERE ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

I think what you meant to do was

```
=IF(C12={0,1,2,3,4,5},"0", IF(C12={6,7,8},"25", IF(C12={9,10},"30", IF(C12>10,"35",""))))
```

### Explanation

The change I made is that I removed the `,""` from every `IF` except for the last one.

This works because each of the nested IFs only evaluate when `logical_expression` is false otherwise it will just return the value associated with that if.

Comment: If you have any feedback please let me know before downvoting!

Comment: Thank you very much, that solved it. Do you know of any way that i can now use these true values (0, 25, 30, 35) to autosum a total? Because as of now they just autosum to 0. (using this formula for multiple rows)

Comment: @tonygouveia What do you mean by autosum?

Comment: I am using this formula on multiple rows and want to total them automatically (35+25+30=90 for example) but as it is now my autosum =SUM(E12:E21) totals to 0 only

Comment: @tonygouveia You want to sum a line of cells together?

Comment: @timotree no need to at-mention the OP in comments. They will see comment notifications anyway.

Comment: Correct, but with that if formula it only comes out as 0

Comment: Edit your ***question*** and provide more detail about what you want to achieve. Without seeing your data it is impossible to determine why your formula returns unexpected results. It is not clear what you are actually testing with `IF(C12={0,1,2,3,4,5},` Is that meant to test C12 for 0 OR 1, OR 2, etc? If so, you need to confirm the formula with Ctrl-Shift-Enter

Comment: @teylyn The advantage of notifying the OP is that it [threads comments](https://stackapps.com/questions/2050/threaded-comments) correctly.

Comment: @tonygouveia Would you like to wait 40 mins to make a new post or just edit your current one?

Comment: Edited my post.

Answer (score 0):

AutoSum or SUM will not work on anything but numbers. Your formula result is not a "number"

[SUM Syntax](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yV3Z7.jpg)

Use the VALUE Function to convert your formula result to a number that you can then AutoSum.

[Example illustrating IF formulas WITH the VALUE function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dyZPq.jpg) which returns the SUM you require.

VALUE Function

> Description
>
> Converts a text string that represents a number to a number.
>
> Syntax
>
> VALUE(text)
>
> The VALUE function syntax has the following arguments:

```
Text    Required. The text enclosed in quotation marks or a reference to a cell containing the text you want to convert.
```