# you've entered too many arguments for this function nested if

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I want to enter several conditions but Excel shows the message "you've entered too many arguments for this function". What I want to do is:

- If AD4 and U4 are equals then enter "xxx"
- Second: If AD4 is blanks but not U4 then enter "xxx"
- Third: If U4 is blank but not AD4 then enter "xxx"

Could you please help me with this?

`=IF(AD4=U4,"REMOVE, RELOAD AND ALREADY PROCESSED UNDER BOTH DUNS", IF(ISBLANK((AD4),IF(NOT(ISBLANK(U4),"REMOVE, RELOAD AND REVERSE KEYING", IF(ISBLANK(U4),IF(NOT(ISBLANK(AD4),"REMOVE AND RELOAD"))))))))`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [If(AND) combination produces "You've entered too many arguments for this function" error](https://superuser.com/questions/856762/ifand-combination-produces-youve-entered-too-many-arguments-for-this-functio)

Comment: Also here: https://superuser.com/questions/1152907/entered-too-many-arguments-for-this-function-4-arguments-nested-if/1152911

Comment: Did my suggestion below help?

Answer (score 1):

```
=IF(UD4=AD4,"REMOVE, RELOAD...",IF(AND(ISBLANK(AD4),NOT(ISBLANK(U4))),"Remove, RELOAD, REVERSE KEYING",IF(AND(ISBLANK(U4),NOT(ISBLANK(AD4))),"Remove and reload")))
```

You can use `AND()` instead of the `IF([x],if[y],...` type setup.